# The significance of the field of the factor in Lenstra’s ECM

Tags: elliptic-curves, prime-numbers, factoring

I am going through Lenstra's Elliptic Curve Factorisation from Silverman's Mathematical Cryptography book.

I have understood the algorithm itself, but unable to understand a specific point the book makes.

We are trying to factor 187.

We use $E: Y^2 = X^3 + 3X + 7 \bmod 187$ with $P = (38, 112)$

When we try to calculate $5P$, we have to calculate the inverse of 11 in 187, which we are unable to since 11 isn't coprime with 187 & hence we are able to find 11 as a factor of 187.

Upto this is clear. However, after this the books says

> We examine more closely why we were not able to compute $5P$ modulo 187.  If we instead look at the elliptic curve $E$ modulo 11, then a quick computation shows that the point $P = (38,112) \equiv (5,2) \pmod{11}$ satisfies $5P = \mathcal O$ in $E(\mathbb F_{11})$. This means that when we attempt to compute $5P$ modulo 11, we end up with the point $\mathcal O$ at infinity, so at some stage of the calculation we have tried to
> divide by zero. But here “zero” means zero in $F_{11}$, so we actually end up trying to find the reciprocal modulo 11 of some integer that is divisible by 11.

We have already factored 187 & found that 11 is one of the factors. So what is the point of computing $5P$ in $\mathbb F_{11}$. What insight does this give us?

Comment: My reading is that "We examine more closely" and the "quick computation" are not intended as steps in the algorithm. They are steps in the explanation of the algorithm.

Comment: @fgrieu - yes, I understand it's not a step in the algo. But I am unable to figure out what exactly it explains - that's the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote invites computing $5\,P$ on the Elliptic Curve of equation $E:\ Y^2\equiv X^3+3X+7\pmod{11}$ in order to experimentally come to the realization this is the point at infinity $\mathcal O$ (the neutral of point addition), and get the intuition that's why the computation of $5\,P$ on the Elliptic Curve of equation $E:\ Y^2\equiv X^3+3X+7\pmod{187}$ (as performed by the algorithm) yields a value that can't be inverted modulo $187$.

This all comes from the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). Possible statements and consequences of that are: for $n=p\,q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ (including $n=187$ , $p=11$ , $q=17$ as in the example)

- Any quantity modulo $n$ can be equivalently computed modulo $p$ and modulo $q$.
- The [ring of integers modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers_modulo_n) $n$, noted $\mathbb Z_n$, has a canonical isomorphism with $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_q$.
- For any integer $z$ in $[0,n)$ we can uniquely define $z_p=z\bmod p$ and $z_q=z\bmod q$, and then it holds $z=\left((q^{-1}\bmod p)\,(z_p-z_q)\bmod p\right)\,q+z_q$.
- For a given Elliptic Curve of equation taken modulo $n$, and points $U$ and $V$ on that curve, if we can compute $U+V$ per the equations of point addition of an Elliptic Curve in a field, yielding $(X,Y)$ ; then we can equivalently do the same for the curves with the same equation taken modulo $p$ and modulo $q$ yielding coordinates $(X_p,Y_p)$ and $(X_q,Y_q)$ , then obtain $(X,Y)$ by twice applying the method in the above bullet point.
- The above for point addition extends to point multiplication by an integer.

> What insight does this give us?

We get the insight that by computing on an Elliptic Curve in the ring $\mathbb Z_n$ for $n$ of (initially) unknown factorization as if it was a field (it's not), we also managed to compute on an Elliptic Curve in the ring $\mathbb Z_p$ where $p$ is an (initially) unknown factor of $n$. And (still without a formal proof, but with an enlightening example) the reason the computation on a curve in $\mathbb Z_n$ hit a non-computable inverse is that the point at infinity $\mathcal O$ was reached on the curve in one of $\mathbb Z_p$ or $\mathbb Z_q$ (assuming $p$ and $q$ are prime, making $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb Z_p$ fields, and $\mathcal O$ on the corresponding curve well-defined).

This let us understand *why* the algorithm works, which in turn allows to reason about it and evaluate it's probability of success (that is of uncovering a non-trivial factor of $n$). When $n$ is the product of distinct primes $p_i$, that probability is the sum of the probabilities that the point at infinity is reached for one the curves for each of the $p_j$, minus the (very low) probability that it's hit simultaneously on all curves.

Comment: How is it concluded that the reason why the gcd did not return 1 is because $5P \bmod 11 = \mathcal O $?

Comment: For your point _"For any integer $z$ in $[0,n)$ we can uniquely define $z_p=z\bmod p$ and $z_q=z\bmod q$, and then it holds $z=\left((q^{-1}\bmod p)\,(z_p-z_q)\bmod p\right)\,q+z_q$"_ - Where can I read more about this - is there any name for this relation - what should I search for?

Comment: @user93353: this is the formula used in RSA with CRT. It condenses the last formula in 1 and the last two in 2 [there](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/crt_rsa.html#rsacalculations) with $z$, $z_p$, $z_q$ (now lowercase) where they have $m$, $m_1$, $m_2$. Wikipedia [has these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm). This formula is a little hard to devise but easily verified using the definition of the $\bmod$ operator. I know no source that cares to carefully make this proof.

Comment: @user93353: Ah, found the official name: generalized to an arbitrary number of factors of $n$, it's Garner’s algorithm. A source is the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), section [14.5.2](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf#page=23). There's no proof, and it's not exactly as I state it, but still that's the closest I get.

Comment: Thank you so much